# Find the expected value of a random variable from the exponential family.

Tags: statistics

Suppose that $X$ is a random variable that belongs to the exponential family with parameter $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and density $f(x)=h(x)c(\theta)exp\{\sum_{j=1}^{m}w_j(\theta)t_j(x)\}$.

I need to prove that for $k\in\{1,...,d\}$,

$\mathbb{E}\big[\sum_{j=1}^{m}\frac{\delta w_j(\theta)}{\delta \theta_k}t_j(X)\big]=-\frac{\delta}{\delta \theta_k}log(c(\theta)$.

I know what the expected value is, but I don't know how to start solving this problem. And what does it mean?